# Why is this MOSFET using lots of power when idle?

Tags: mosfet

[image]

[image]

The mosfet is used as complementary pair for the power amplifier and is used to drive the 8 ohm load.

Is it normal for a mosfet to consume 2 W when idle? Both the upper and lower  consume beefy power and they are attached to a breadboard. I'm worried since it might damage the motherboard.

Also it really gets super hot when touched. 2 watts for idle is a lot.

Comment: you've actually built this circuit or just simulated it? 2W at idle is absolutely not normal

Comment: Looks like you built a class A (or AB at worst) amplifier. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_amplifier#Class_A Yes it is normal to dissipate a lot of power, but it is easier to get low distortion.

Comment: i build it and it gets real hot. breadboard is now melted... even if it hs metal heatsink connected.

Comment: I think a small resistor in each source connection would improve the design. It will limit current and create a slight feedback as U(GS) decreases.

Comment: You will have both FETs on all the time causing them to heat up. Your zener almost guarantees that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With, I assume, 12.5V across each output transistor when idle, the idle power for each transistor is:

\$P = 12.5V \cdot I_D \$

For *P = 2W*, the idle current works out to 160mA.  What idle current did you design for?

Consider replacing the zener diode with a \$V_{BE}\$ multiplier so that you can adjust the idle current and thus, the idle power as desired.

Comment: correction, vbe is for bjt

Comment: @vvavepacket, no, I'm suggesting that a **BJT** configured as a **V_BE multiplier** replace the zener diode.  See, for example:  http://www.st-andrews.ac.uk/~www_pa/Scots_Guide/audio/part2/page3.html

Answer (score 2):

*Is it normal for a mosfet to consume 2 watts under idle operations?*
**(in your design) YES**  [**try this**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/#$+0+5.3E-7+5.459815003314424+50+5.0+38%0Af+384+192+448+192+1+1.5%0Af+384+320+448+320+0+1.5%0Aw+448+176+448+144+0%0Ac+384+144+448+144+0+1.0E-11+-4.254152129181939%0Ac+448+288+384+288+0+1.0E-11+10.566851426587078%0Ac+448+368+384+368+0+1.0E-11+-2.617772059077328%0Aw+448+336+448+368+0%0Ag+448+368+448+416+0%0Ar+384+144+384+192+0+5.0%0Ar+384+320+384+368+0+5.0%0A172+496+80+544+80+0+6+25.0+25.0+0.0+0.0+0.5+Voltage%0Aw+352+320+384+320+0%0Aw+352+192+384+192+0%0Ac+288+192+224+192+0+9.999999999999999E-5+21.555520541257675%0Ac+288+320+224+320+0+9.999999999999999E-5+3.4274447295173247%0As+384+320+384+288+0+0+false%0Aw+224+192+224+320+0%0Ar+608+256+608+304+0+20.5%0Ag+608+304+608+336+0%0Ac+480+256+608+256+0+9.999999999999999E-5+11.885768460121081%0As+448+256+480+256+0+0+false%0Ar+288+320+288+384+0+1000.0%0Ar+288+192+288+144+0+1000.0%0Aw+448+80+448+144+0%0Aw+384+80+288+80+0%0Aw+288+80+288+144+0%0Ag+288+384+288+416+0%0Aw+448+208+448+224+0%0Aw+352+192+320+192+0%0Aw+352+320+320+320+0%0Aw+288+320+320+320+0%0Aw+288+192+320+192+0%0Ag+160+400+160+432+0%0Ar+336+256+448+256+0+992000.0%0Aw+224+352+224+320+0%0Aw+464+80+448+80+0%0Aw+496+80+464+80+0%0Aw+448+224+448+256+0%0As+288+256+336+256+0+1+false%0Aw+448+304+448+288+0%0Aw+448+288+448+256+0%0Aw+448+80+384+80+0%0Av+160+352+160+400+0+1+1000.0+5.0+0.0+0.0+0.5%0A174+192+352+192+416+0+1000.0+0.0149+Resistance%0Aw+192+352+160+352+0%0Aw+224+352+224+384+0%0Aw+192+416+160+416+0%0Aw+160+416+160+400+0%0Aw+224+384+208+384+0%0A162+288+192+288+256+1+11.0+1.0+0.0+0.0%0A162+288+256+288+320+1+11.0+1.0+0.0+0.0%0Ao+17+64+1+35+5.0+9.765625E-5+0+-1%0Ao+10+64+0+35+34.99601159652819+0.6999202319305639+1+-1%0Ao+34+64+0+291+5.0+0.0125+2+-1%0A)

[image]
SO Why does when CMOS Logic doesn't?
Logic operates in the saturated  mode. These are both in the linear mode. With a large Vgs ( > 1.5V) the Rds is low enough to short out the power supply with what you have.

V+ = 25V  and if Vds balanced or = 12V each, there will be considerable power lost.

Also the Capacitor choices are a bit non-ideal and there is a risk instability if the output is unloaded. ( ie wild oscillation)

Consider how CMOS works at 5V. Using 1.5V thresholds the gate voltages are saturated 
Then use suitable input biasing to reduce the Vgs for each.  The zener only is using 0.2mA and that doesn't even activate it.

Regardless, the Gate Voltage is too high when the output is in the linear region.
(you didn't ask for a solution, so I am hoping you will find it on your own and report back)

When it works it will still be 80% efficient at best, which is why Class D is so popular.

Comment: Unfortunately the poo controlled characteristics of Vgs vs Rds vs Vds make this non-linear amplifier too sensitive  too distorted to be to be useful for larg signal input and full swing into 8 ohms. YOu can determine the maximum power transfer by changing the load resistor but then the output impedance will be so high that the dampening factor will be poor. Also input impedance will change along the VI curve so additional wave form distortion can occur. It is very high gain with no load and lower voltage gain in this design, making it a sub-optimal design for linear Speaker drivers

Comment: Complementary drain outputs are used for high voltage gain and logic saturated high speed outputs. Whereas complementary source outputs like the classic Class A-B config are better for high current linear output with independence of Supply voltage on gate to gate DC bias unlike this design where Zener voltage changes significantly with V+ due to high ESR of zener. ALso thermal matching of bias diode to output drivers is missing in the above design, which is inherent in Class A-B design when diode is thermally attached to drivers.